# Extracting POI from Openstreetmap (*.osm)

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, extract, point-of-interest

I've searched the web and found out that "osmosis" is the key.
also, this blog http://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osmosis/ gave me a huge hint and i made it to extract POI tag by tag
(by the way, i am using windwos)

[image]

as you know, there are hundreds of tags in OSM and going through all the tags and paste that in the command window is not feasible.
so, instead of writing "amenity.school", i used "amenity.*"

[image]

of course, it doesn't seem to work.
You have any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to use the node-key filter instead: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.46#--node-key_.28--nk.29

Comment: awesome! it works perfect!

Comment: You can self-answer your question with the correct command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

easy.
1. download *.osm.pbf
2. install osmosis
3. in the command window type

osmosis --rbf INPUT.osm.pbf --nk keyList="amenity" --wx OUTPUT.osm